# Python code from previous file is coming up in new file

Tags: python

new to coding and lots of the vernacular is not yet under my belt.

I was practicing some very basic stuff, and I created a new project after finishing the last exercise. All the code looks good and should work, but I'm getting an error that is quoting code from the previous exercise. Am I missing something?

Here's the code I'm trying to execute:

```
# Enter Calculation: 5 * 6
# answer should be 30

num1, operator, num2 = raw_input('Enter calculation:').split()

num1 = int(num1)
operator = int(operator)
num2 = int(num2)

if operator == "+":
    print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1+num2))
elif operator == "-":
    print("{} - {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1 - num2))
elif operator == "*":
    print("{} * {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1 * num2))
elif operator == "/":
    print("{} / {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1 / num2))
```

And when I enter 5 * 6 it brings up this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Rocky\PycharmProjects\PythonTutorial.py\pythontut.py", line 
5, in <module>
miles = float(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 5 * 6
```

The code for this previous exercise is:

```
# Problem: Receive miles and convert to kilometers
# Kilometers = miles * 1.60934
# Enter miles 5
# 5 miles = 8.04
miles = float(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
def kilo_conversion(miles):
    if miles > 0 or miles < 0:
    conversion = miles * 1.60934
        print 'Your distance of {} miles in kilometers is: {}'.format(miles,             
        conversion)
    else:
        print 'Nice. Try again with a number greater than zero!'
kilo_conversion(miles)
```

Comment: insted of `5 * 6`, try `5*6`

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have nearly enough information to solve your problem. Are you _sure_ you're executing the correct file? If you've modified the file from the last exercise for the new exercise, are you sure you've _saved it_? If you're using a fancy IDE, are you sure it's executing the file you want?

Comment: Maybe the problem is `operator = int(operator)` ? You're trying to parse `*` to int

Comment: Are these exercises in different files or in the same, one under another?

Comment: Thanks. so it gave me the same error, but now it says 5*6 instead -__-

Comment: @ksai `5      *           6 == 5*6` gives `True`

Comment: In PyCharm for example you can see the running file in the top-right. Other IDEs will display something similar, usually in the top-right corner. Make sure to name your files differently (best practice would probably be to name them after the problem they solve).

Comment: I figured it was a little vague. Sorry about that. Let me try some of your suggestions!

Comment: @BrightOne they're in different projects, I moved it out of the first project into a new one, hoping that it would fix it, but it did not.

Comment: Ok, so I double-checked and renamed the files to be much different from each other. I even closed the file and reopened it, but now it gives me this message:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Rocky\PycharmProjects\PythonTutorial.py\pythontut.py
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Rocky\PycharmProjects\PythonTutorial.py\pythontut.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, still learning :p

Comment: @ACE just removed it, but it's giving me that error message

Answer (score 1):

operator variable can't be typecasted to int. Try removing that line.

```
num1, operator, num2 = input('Enter calculation:').split()

num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)

if operator == "+":
    print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1+num2))
elif operator == "-":
    print("{} - {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1 - num2))
elif operator == "*":
    print("{} * {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1 * num2))
elif operator == "/":
    print("{} / {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1 / num2))
```

Comment: yes, when we typecast "*" to int, it will throw error as "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*'". And also instead of raw_input one need to use input in version 3.x onwards

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT! Thanks for the help, guys. I just closed everything and copy/pasted the code into a new project. I think I just needed to clear the air. Still getting an error message, but at least it pertains to the code in the window. Thanks again :)